# Crossing UK border with EEA family permit in old passport

Tags: visas

On 12/04/19 l’ve received my EEA Family Permit visa. However now I’m worried that I may have problems at the passport control in the UK during my first trip. As I applied for a visa with my current at the moment passport that has my maiden name. Later I had to apply for a new international passport (takes 2 months in my country). Therefore I’ve got as my traveling documents: annulled old passport with maiden name and FP visa, new passport with married name, translation of marriage certificate. By the way my last name in new passport is spelled a little differently to marriage certificate due to translation rules in my country. 
Could you please advise regarding my situation, as I have less than 12 days left before my trip.

Answer (score 2):

> annulled old passport with maiden name and FP visa, new passport with married name, translation of marriage certificate

So far so good. The old expired passport with visa + new passport is a classic combo used and recognized everywhere (I myself did dozens of border crossings into the US with that combo over eight years) and a name change should be accompanied by an official document.

> By the way my last name in new passport is spelled a little differently to marriage certificate due to translation rules in my country

This is a very big problem. You need to reconcile this somehow. You could (should?) get a new passport with the right name. Or maybe change the name on the marriage certificate if that's possible. Or you could contact the consulate of the country issuing the visa and ask them to countersign a sworn affidavit you make about your names.

Comment: downvoter care to comment?